# Randomly select Elements of 4D matrix in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, random, 4d

I have a 4D matrix with dimensions 7x4x24x10 (Lets call it main_mat). I want to get a matrix of size 7x4x24 (rand_mat) so that each element of this (rand_mat) matrix is actually a uniformly random draw from the main matrix (main_mat). I am sorry if I have not put the question clearly, so I try to explain:

I have a stack of 24 sheets of 7x4 elements, and I have 10 such stacks. What I want is that I get a single stack of 24 sheets of 7x4 elements in such a way that every element out of resultant single stack is uniformly randomly drawn from exactly same sheet number from within 10 stacks. How can I do it without using loops?

Comment: Your question is still not 100% clear to me. Do you want to get a 7x4x24 matrix with numbers chosen from the 7x4x24x10 matrix so that every place in the 7x4x24 matrix could only be one of the x10 in the other matrix?

Comment: Thats right. For example element (1,1,1) can only be among 10 elements available at this position i,e. they can only be from (1,1,1,randi(10)) and so on.

Comment: I tried something like this ' k = datasample(j,1,4);' and the results were that it randomly starts from one of the 7x4 sheet, and then all remaining 23 sheets are in successive order. I don't know if I am doing something wrong here.

Comment: @AWAbid - OK, I think I know what you want.  For each position in this 7 x 4 x 24 matrix, you want to make sure that we uniformly select from one out of the 10 stacks?  For example, given position `(1,1,1)` in the output, we would randomly choose from a stack such that `(1,1,1,randi(10))`?

Comment: Thats correct @rayryeng Thank you for understanding.

Comment: Kudos...I am waiting :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I am interpreting what you want correctly, for each unique 3D position in this  matrix of 7 x 4 x 24, you want to be sure that we randomly sample from one out of the 10 stacks that share the same 3D spatial position.

What I would recommend you do is generate random integers that are from 1 to 10 that is of size 7 x 4 x 24 long, then use [`sub2ind`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sub2ind.html) along with [`ndgrid`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ndgrid.html).  You can certainly use `randi` as you have alluded to in the comments.

We'd use `ndgrid` to generate a grid of 3D coordinates, then use the random integers we generated to access the fourth dimension.  Given the fact that your 4D matrix is stored in `A`, do something like this:

```
rnd = randi(size(A,4), size(A,1), size(A,2), size(A,3));
[R,C,D] = ndgrid(1:size(A,1), 1:size(A,2), 1:size(A,3));
ind = sub2ind(size(A), R, C, D, rnd);
B = A(ind);
```

Bear in mind that the above code will work for **any** 4D matrix.  The first line of code generates a 7 x 4 x 24 matrix of random integers between `[1,10]`.  Next, we generate a 3D grid of spatial coordinates and then use `sub2ind` to generate column-major indices where we can sample from the matrix `A` in such a way where each unique 3D spatial location of the matrix `A` only samples from one chunk and only one chunk.  We then use these column-major indices to sample from `A` to produce our output matrix `B`.

Comment: Impressive, question marked favorite so I can reference this.

Answer (score 0):

This problem might not be solvable without the use of loops. One way that could work is:

```
mainMatrix = ... (7x4x24x10 matrix)
randMatrix = zeros(mainMatrix(:,1,1,1), mainMatrix(1,:,1,1), mainMatrix(1,1,:,1))
for x = 1:length(mainMatrix(:,1,1,1))
  for y = 1:length(mainMatrix(1,:,1,1))
    for z = 1:length(mainMatrix(1,2,:,1))
      randMatrix(x,y,z) = mainMatrix(x,y,z,randi(10))
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: It is most certainly solvable without loops.  See my answer.  However, I will admit that it's a bit memory intensive.  This would work if the matrix is very large an this has very minimal memory footprint.